# Can I send sms using twilio gem in India and Out side of india

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

Can I send sms using twilio gem in India and Out side of india, I am getting
below msg from my rails app when I try to send sms.

The 'From' number 'XXXXX' is not a valid phone number or shortcode.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code you are using to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The reason you are getting this is potentially because you are using a trial account, and have not yet registered your number.

That being the case, all you need to do is verify your caller ID by going to [this page](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/verified).

Let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use smscountry gem to send sms in India & other countries. 
Below is the link to the Gem Docs:

https://github.com/sriram15690/smsCountryGem